# ¿ Cual es la sintaxis para agregar un campo a una columna?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

necesito saber la sintaxis para agregar un campo a una columna, es decir, tengo que crear un bloque anónimo donde le pido al usuario que me escriba un nombre, después de eso tengo que crear un procedimiento para agregar el nombre que me ha pasado.

Aquí le pido al usuario que me escriba un nombre:

```
set serveroutput on
set verify off
set echo off
accept constituent prompt 'Introduce el nombre del constituente: '
begin
  alta_constituent(&constituent);
end;
```

Y aquí tengo que añadir una nueva fila a la tabla con el nombre que me ha pasado antes:

```
create or replace procedure alta_constituent(constituent)
is
begin
insert into constituent
(nom_constituent) values (&constituent)
end alta_constituent;
```

Sé que el código es incompleto pero solo necesito la estructura, muchas gracias.

Comment: Entiendo que esa tabla es la que está definida en esta otra pregunta tuya, ¿no? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153892/como-utilizo-esta-consulta-en-una-funci%C3%B3n?noredirect=1#153892 En ese caso creo nos faltaría saber si la PK de la tabla es autoincremental o no y si el campo Aa_constituent puede ser nulo o no.

Comment: Sí, es la misma.

Comment: ¿Y el resto de dudas que te he comentado?...

Answer (score 0):

para poder hacer lo que quieres tienes que hacerlo con ejecución de sentencias dinámicas, con EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Sería algo así:

```
V_CONSULTA :='INSERT INTO ....';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_CONSULTA;
```