# ¿ Como utilizo esta consulta en una función?

Tags: plsql

Tengo que resolver este ejercicio:

> Crear un script que le pasará una ciudad y nos devolverá el nombre y
>   el NIF de todas las empresas transportistas que han realizado un
>   traslado desde empresas situada en esta ciudad.

Tengo que pedir una ciudad en un bloque anónimo así:

```
set serveroutput on
set verify off
set echo off
accept ciudad prompt 'Introduce el nombre de la ciudad: '
begin
  agregar_ciudad (&ciudad);
end;
```

Ahora tengo que crear una funcion en la cual haga una consulta que me obtenga lo que me pide el enunciado, la consulta es esta:

```
create or replace function obtener_ciudad (ciudad varchar)
return varchar
is
  ciudad varchar;
begin
SELECT NIF_EMPTRANSPORT, NOM_EMPTRANSPORT 
  FROM EMPRESATRANSPORTISTA
  WHERE NIF_EMPTRANSPORT IN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT NIF_EMPTRANSPORT 
        FROM TRASLLAT_EMPRESATRANSPORT
        WHERE nif_empresa IN 
           (SELECT nif_empresa 
              FROM EMPRESAPRODUCTORA
              WHERE lower(ciutat_empresa)= (&ciudad)))
ORDER BY NOM_EMPTRANSPORT; 
end obtener_ciudad;
```

Esta consulta me filtra las empresas de Madrid y yo quiero filtrar por la ciudad que le pido al usuario. ¿ Alguien me puede ayudar ?

Saludos.

Editado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar las tablas y los datos que tienen?

Comment: Sí, ahora lo edito.

Comment: La consulta en si ya la tengo, lo que necesito saber es que tengo que poner para que en vez de filtrar por Madrid me filtre por la ciudad que se le pasa en el bloque.

Comment: No entiendo lo que dices de Madrid si en la función ya le estás pasando un parámetro &ciudad.

Comment: Me refiero a que en la consulta que yo he escrito me filtra por la ciudad de Madrid, yo lo que necesito es filtrar por una ciudad que se le pase desde otro bloque, no sé si me explico.

Comment: En la consulta que has escrito no aparece Madrid por ninguna parte. De hecho aparece WHERE lower(ciutat_empresa)= (&ciudad). No sé si te refieres a eso o a la llamada que haces a la función.

Comment: Si, perdón, antes la había escrito con Madrid. Aunque ahora este con &ciudad no me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema es que estás buscando en la tabla `EMPRESAPRODUCTORA` en vez de en `EMPRESA_TRANSPORTISTA` que es la que está relacionada con `TRASLLAT_EMPRESATRANSPORTISTA`

```
create or replace function obtener_ciudad (ciudad IN varchar)
return varchar
is
  ciudad varchar;
begin
SELECT NIF_EMPTRANSPORT, NOM_EMPTRANSPORT 
  FROM EMPRESATRANSPORTISTA
  WHERE NIF_EMPTRANSPORT IN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT NIF_EMPTRANSPORT 
        FROM TRASLLAT_EMPRESATRANSPORT
        WHERE nif_empresa IN 
           (SELECT nif_empresa 
              FROM EMPRESA_TRANSPORTISTA
              WHERE lower(ciutat_empresa)= (&ciudad)))
ORDER BY NOM_EMPTRANSPORT; 
end obtener_ciudad;
```

Comment: La consulta es correcta. Sólo tengo que modificar lo de     WHERE lower(ciutat_empresa)= (&ciudad))) para que me filtre por la ciudad introducida en el bloque.

Comment: ¿Modificar cómo?